# On the definition of equivalence of categories

Tags: category-theory

> Given two categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$, they are said to be *equivalent* if there exist two functors $F: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ and $G: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$, such that $F \circ G \cong id_{\mathcal{C}}$ and $G \circ F \cong id_{\mathcal{D}}$.

Now thinking about this definition, I'd like to know why do we require the notion of natural isomorphism between the functors. Why wouldn't the following definition be a better measure for the "sameness" of a category?

> Given two categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$, they are said to be *equivalent* if there exist two functors $F: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ and $G: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$, such that for any $\mathcal{C}$-object $A$, we have that $(F \circ G)(A) = A$ and $\mathcal{D}$-object $B$ we have $(G \circ F)(B) = B$.

Is this new definition any different than the one I wrote above?

Comment: Do you really want no conditions at all on what $F\circ G$ and $G\circ F$ do to morphisms? That seems very strange.

Answer (score 6):

As Andreas says in the comments, your new condition places no conditions on what $F \circ G$ and $G \circ F$ do to morphisms, which doesn't make any sense. For example, if $C$ and $D$ are both categories with one object, then every pair of functors $F : C \to D, G : D \to C$ satisfies your condition.

You may have intended to ask about the following condition: what if we just asked that $F \circ G = \text{id}_C$ and $G \circ F = \text{id}_D$? This is an *isomorphism* of categories, and is the obvious translation to the world of categories of the notion of an isomorphism of groups, or rings, or etc. So why don't we use this definition?

The basic practical problem is that isomorphism just doesn't capture examples where we want to express that two categories are "essentially the same" which is what equivalence is for. As a simple example, the category of finite sets is equivalent to the category whose objects are the finite sets $\{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$ (where if $n = 0$ this set is empty) and whose morphisms are the functions between these. This is a [skeleton](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/skeleton) of the category of finite sets. But you will find that it's not possible to write down an isomorphism of categories between the two, only an equivalence; an isomorphism of categories induces a bijection on objects and that's impossible here, because the skeleton only has countably many objects but the category of finite sets itself has a class's worth of objects.

More philosophically, working with isomorphisms of categories amounts to ignoring the fact that natural transformations exist, and the whole reason category theory was invented in the first place was to talk about natural transformations! In algebraic topology, Eilenberg and MacLane wanted to discuss the precise sense in which different constructions of invariants such as cohomology were "the same" (e.g. singular and de Rham cohomology for smooth manifolds), and what this required them to do is to define categories, in order to define functors (namely cohomology functors), in order to define natural transformations (namely comparisons between cohomology functors). Functors are fundamentally objects which themselves live in a category, whose morphisms are natural transformations, and "meaningful" statements about functors are statements that ought to be invariant under natural isomorphism, in the same way that meaningful statements about groups are statements that ought to be invariant under isomorphism.